# Conservation of momentum in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, conservation-laws, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Let $P_x=P_{1x}+P_{2x}$ be the operator for the total linear momentum of an isolated system of two particles labeled 1 and 2. The questioned asked to show that $\langle P_x \rangle$ remains constant in time.

I looked up the solution of the above problem. They started off by writing the expression for hamiltonian of the system as $$H=\frac{1}{2m}(P_{1x}^2+P_{2x}^2)+V(x_{12})$$
where $x_{12}=x_1-x_2$.

Then they used the relation $\frac{d\langle P_x\rangle}{dt}=\frac{1}{i\textstyle \hbar }[\langle P_x \rangle,H]$ to show that $\frac{d\langle P_x\rangle}{dt}$ will be equal to zero which will prove that $\langle P_x\rangle$ is a constant.

Now the first part of the hamiltonian, $(P_{1x}^2+P_{2x}^2)$ is understandable. But the second part $V(x_{12})$ is not understandable. Why the total potential energy of the two particle-system is dependent on the separation of both the particles? Shouldn't it actually depend on the sum of $x_1$ and $x_2$ since it is the total potential potential energy (just like $P_{1x}^2$ and $P_{2x}^2$ got added in the first part)?

Comment: You can imagine there are only two particles in the space. If they do interact with each other, the potential should not depend on where we choose the origin of our coordinate, which is to say, $V$ must be a function of their relative positions $x_1-x_2$.

Comment: @AndyChen that should be an answer. Admittedly it's a brief answer, but then only a brief answer is needed :-)

Comment: Angle brackets use `\langle\rangle`, not `\lt\gt`. I've edited that for you.

Comment: @AndyChen oh..I got it. So we assume the energy of the first particle as 0 and then the energy of the second particle will be (energy of the first particle + P.D. between both the particles) which will ultimately equal to just the P.D. since we assumed the energy of the first particle as 0...right?

Comment: Well, your understanding is somewhat inaccurate. We do not have to  assume the energy of the first particle is $0$. In fact, there are many times in quantum mechanics when we cannot even distinguish the first and second particles. You may learn about this when you get in touch with the topic of "identical particles".

Comment: The point here is that, since $x_1+x_2$ and $x_1-x_2$ also span the whole coordinate as $x_1$ and $x_2$ do, we can express $V$ in $x_1+x_2$ and $x_1-x_2$ with $V=V(x_1+x_2,x_1-x_2)$, right? However, we know the potential energy of the system does not depend on where we choose the origin, so $x_1+x_2$ should not a variable that $V$ can depend on.

Answer (score 1):

The potential energy of the particles is only dependend on their relative location to each other and therefore only on $x_{12}=x_1-x_2$. We have:
\begin{align*}
[P_x,x_{12}]
=[P_{x1}+P_{x2},x_1-x_2]
=[P_{x1},x_1]-[P_{x2},x_2]
=(-i\hbar)-(-i\hbar)=0 \\
\Rightarrow
[P_x,V(x_{12})]=0
\end{align*}
which result in $[P_x,H]=0$ as the momentum operators commute with themselves and each other. According to the [Ehrenfest theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem) you already mentioned, we therefore have:
$$\frac{\mathrm d\langle P_x\rangle}{\mathrm dt}
=\frac{1}{i\hbar}\langle\underbrace{[P_x,H]}_{=0}\rangle
+\left\langle\underbrace{\frac{\partial P_x}{\partial t}}_{=0}\right\rangle=0.$$
By the way, the upper result (where the commutator vanishes) can be generalized. If you have two operators $A$ and $B$ with constant commutator $[A,B]=\lambda$, then you can prove by induction that $[A,B^n]=n\lambda B^{n-1}$ and taking a function $f$ that can be written as a Taylor series, you get $[A,f(B)]=\lambda f'(B)$. Therefore taking $[p,x]=-i\hbar$, you get $[p,V(x)]=-i\hbar V'(x)$, which is how quantum mechanics falls back to classical mechanis for the expectation values using the Ehrenfest theorem.

Comment: Is $P_{1x}$=$P_{2x}$? The momentum operator can't change. It's always equal to $\frac{-i}{h}\frac{d}{dx}$. Isn't it?

Comment: No, the two operators are not the same as they correspond to the derivative of the location of their respective particle. We therefore have $P_{x1}=-i\hbar\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x_1}$ and $P_{x2}=-i\hbar\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x_2}$.

Comment: $x$ is a variable. How is $dx_1$ different from $dx_2$?

Comment: You have two particles and therefore a position $x_1$ for the first and a position $x_2$ for the second. Keep in mind that you can have expressions, where they both appear, like for example their difference in the potential energy. The wave function looks also like $\psi(x_1,x_2)$, where $\psi(x_1,x_2)\mathrm d x_1\mathrm d x_2$ gives you the probability of finding the first particle in an area of $\mathrm d x_1$ around $x_1$ and the second particle in an area of $\mathrm d x_2$ around $x_2$.

Comment: As a result, you need to have two different position operators $x_1$ and $x_2$ as well as two different momentum operators $P_{x1}$ and $P_{x2}$, that derive with respect to their variable.